# Gradle Project Refresh Failed in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When i was trying to clean/run project it shows gradle project refresh failed. any one suggest me.

Here is the issue:

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.12/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read below process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: It looks like you just ran out of RAM. Try closing some other software to free it up.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do the following:

Choose the invalidate caches option in "File" and then quit android studio

Remove your .gradle folder in your home directory and restart android studio

Then rebuild the project.